# Asserting stdin is open

Tags: c, stdin, stdio

I have function in C that assumes stdin is open. I want to add an assertion in front of it to make sure stdin is not closed by anyone. How can I check that stdin isn't closed by anyone?

```
assert(is_open(stdin));
```

Comment: Why would you be concerned about this - what makes you think something else in your code is silly enough to close stdin?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I work in a company. One can write a function A() that opens and closes a file when it's done. Some other programmer can pass STDIN as a parameter. If my function is called after A() function, it won't find STDIN on. That's why.

Comment: @DanParadox: then your colleagues should adopt the principle that a function should close a `FILE*` if and only if it opened it.

Comment: The function A() can't be passed stdin because it is open before the function starts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't find out whether a `FILE*` has been closed. `fclose` might `free` the `FILE` object it points to, so that object's contents may be undefined after `fclose`. This is true even of `stdin`. The solution I proposed previously was wrong. Sorry about that.

The best you can do on a POSIX platform is something like

```
bool stdin_open()
{
    errno = 0;
    fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_GETFD);
    return errno == EBADF;
}
```

though that really tells you something about the standard input FD, rather than the `stdin` object.